# Jira Implement custom page / button

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

We need an easy way for our Jira Service Desk agents to specify that they are on duty. This is because that user will recieve SMS notifications for new issues.

Today we assign a specific user role for the agent(s) on duty, but this process is a little complicated (and boring) to do every day. What I would like is to have either:

A button: "I'm on duty".

Or better: a list of all agents with checkboxes, easily accessible.

The button or checkboxes should then set either a user role, or a custom property for each affected user.

Is this possible to achieve in Jira? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create (or update your existing) jira plugin by some action page with needed view, or add web-item for user.
Look [here](http://www.j-tricks.com/tutorials/extending-jira-actions) and [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/jira-architecture/web-fragments/view-issue-page-locations) for ideas.

Comment: Thanks for you input. I was hoping to avoid creating a plugin, but I guess there is no other way...